# Removing Instance of Video when Finished

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video

I did a file/import/video and pointed to a video on my server and this is all on the first frame.  On my aa layer I have the following:

```
 stop();
 import fl.video.VideoEvent;
 intro.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, fPlay);

 function fPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
 gotoAndPlay(2);
 }
```

As you can see, when the video finishes, it hops to frame 2 and continues to the website.  What started happening on a few occasions, is the timeline would randomly jump back to frame 2 for no apparent reason.  I'm assuming it's because I didn't remove the instance of the video, or something along those lines?  This whole issue on;y started when I introduced the video.

Can someone shed some light?  If it is removing the Listener, can you show me how to write it?  I tried a few times to remove it, but would get errors about not having enough parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Listener:
`intro.removeEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, fPlay);`

But u need to use it before you hop to another frame.

To remove the instance of the video:
`removeChild(intro);`

Same rule as above, need to be used before changing frames.

Comment: Hi Zrean, so I would put both of these pieces of code just above my gotoAndPlay(2);?

Comment: @Christopher Hunt No, not both, only one of them needed depending on what you wanna do. If you wanna remove the eventListener then the first, and if you wanna remove the instance of the video then the second. You could also put both in but that would be overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Otherwise, yes, you put the desired piece of code just above gotoAndPlay(2);